# Cumulative link model in JAGS or BUGS

Tags: bayesian, ordinal-data, jags, bugs, multinomial-logit

I'm trying to implement a cumulative link model in JAGS. My outcome variable (Likert-style questionnaire) has four categories. There is currently no predictor in the model, I will add them once the most basic model works.

I based my model implementation on the description of the cumulative link model by Agresti (2002), Categorical Data Analysis, Chapter 7. Let *pr<sub>i,j</sub>* = Pr{ *Y<sub>i</sub>* = *j* } denote the probability that the response of an individual falls in the *j*-th category, and let *g<sub>i,j</sub>* denote the corresponding cumulative probability *g<sub>i,j</sub>* = Pr{ *Y<sub>i</sub>* ≤ *j* } that the response falls in the *j*-th category or below, so *g<sub>i,j</sub>* = *pr<sub>i,1</sub>* + *pr<sub>i,2</sub>*+ ... *pr<sub>i,j</sub>*. Furthermore, we define a link function *f* such that the transformed cumulative probabilities are a linear function of some predictors: *f(g<sub>i,j</sub>)* = *a<sub>j</sub>* + *x'<sub>i</sub>b*. I currently only have the intercepts *a<sub>j</sub>* in my model, no *x'<sub>i</sub>***b*.The link function *f* is the logit function.

Now, my code looks as follows:

```
model
{
   for(i in 1:N) 
   {

     Y[i]  ~ dcat(pr[i,1:4])

     #####################
     logit(g[i,1]) <- a[1]
     logit(g[i,2]) <- a[2] 
     logit(g[i,3]) <- a[3] 
     g[i,4] <- 1

     ######################
     pr[i,1]   <- g[i,1]
     pr[i,2]   <- g[i,2] - g[i,1]
     pr[i,3]   <- g[i,3] - g[i,2]
     pr[i,4]   <- 1 - g[i,3]

  }
  #######################
  # Priors
  #######################

  a[1] ~ dnorm(0,1e-3)
  a[2] ~ dnorm(0,1e-3)
  a[3] ~ dnorm(0,1e-3) 
}
```

And here are the data:

```
    N = 648

    Y = {3 0 2 2 3 1 2 3 3 3 2 1 3 1 3 3 2 1 3 3 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 3 3 2 3 0    2 2 2 2 1 2 3 3 0 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 3 2 2 1 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 1 1 3 3 1 3 3 1 2 2 0 2 2 0 1 2 1 3 2 2 1 3 1 3 1 2 3 2 1 2 1 1 2 0 0 3 3 2 3 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 0 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 1 3 3 2 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 1 3 1 2 0 1 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 1 0 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 3 3 1 2 0 2 2 1 0 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 1 1 3 2 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 0 2 2 1 1 3 0 2 1 0 2 3 1 2 0 3 1 3 1 0 3 3 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 3 2 0 0 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 0 2 3 3 1 2 2 1 2 3 1 2 2 0 2 2 2 1 2 2 3 1 0 3 0 3 3 1 1 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 1 3 3 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 1 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 3 1 2 0 3 2 1 0 2 3 3 0 0 1 0 3 3 3 2 2 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 0 1 1 2 3 2 2 0 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 3 1 1 3 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 0 2 1 2 2 2 2 3 0 2 2 2 3 2 1 2 3 1 3 0 3 3 0 1 3 0 2 3 2 0 3 3 1 2 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 1 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 1 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 3 1 2 2 2 3 2 0 0 3 2 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 1 2 2 0 2 3 1 2 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 3 0 0 2 2 2 3 0 2 2 3 2 3 1 2 2 2 3 3 1 3 1 2 1 3 3 3 3 1 0 3 3 1 2 3 0 1 2 2 3 1 1 3 1 0 2 1 3 2 1 2 3 3 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 1 3 1 2 1 2 2 0 0 1 2 1 1 3 3 1 2 1 2 3 2 3 3 2 1 2 0 0 2 2 1 2 3 2 2 3 1 2 2 0 2 1 2 2 2 0 1 2 0 0 0 2 1 0 3 1 2 2 1 2 1 3 2 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 0 3 2 2 1}
```

When I try to run this model, JAGS says:

```
    Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values,
    n.chains = n.chains,  : 
    Error in node Y[3]
    Node inconsistent with parents
```

I can't find the problem here, and I can't find any implementation of the cumulative link model in JAGS/BUGS on the web. Has someone an idea what is wrong here?

Comment: There's an entire chapt er about this, with lots of examples and R and JAGS code, in DBDA2E. See Ch 23. https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/

Comment: Thank you very much John. I actually first learned to do Bayesian data analysis through your blog a few years ago, but I really didn't remember there was a chapter about this in your book (and it didn't show up in my Google searches).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, but just a couple of small modifications were needed.  First, the dcat distribution response should be >=1 but yours start at 0, so you just need to have Y <- Y + 1.  Second, JAGS isn't smart enough to figure out that a needs to be sorted when initialising the model, so you need to provide initial values where a[1] < a[2] < a[3] (or alternatively sort a within the model, but the initial values option is easier).  The following code works for me:

```
model <- '
model
{
   for(i in 1:N) 
   {

     Y[i]  ~ dcat(pr[i,1:4])

     #####################
     logit(g[i,1]) <- a[1]
     logit(g[i,2]) <- a[2] 
     logit(g[i,3]) <- a[3] 
     g[i,4] <- 1

     ######################
     pr[i,1]   <- g[i,1]
     pr[i,2]   <- g[i,2] - g[i,1]
     pr[i,3]   <- g[i,3] - g[i,2]
     pr[i,4]   <- 1 - g[i,3]

  }

  #######################
  # Priors
  #######################

  a[1] ~ dnorm(0,1e-3)
  a[2] ~ dnorm(0,1e-3)
  a[3] ~ dnorm(0,1e-3)
}
#data# N, Y
#monitor# a
#inits# a
'

N <- 648

Y <- c(3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1)

Y <- Y+1
a <- c(-2,0,2)

library('runjags')

results <- run.jags(model)
results
```

Hope that helps.

Matt